# Float image left on titlepage

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to achieve this:

[image]

So far, this is what I've tried:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}


\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[letterpaper, top=4cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=4cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}


\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}



\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}


\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}\centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{./uchile.png}
\end{wrapfigure}


{ \LARGE UNIVERSIDAD DE CHILE \\[0.1cm]}
{ \LARGE FACSO \\[0.1cm]}
{ \LARGE DEPARTAMENTO EDUCACIÓN \\[0.1cm]}

\HRule 
{ \Huge TITLE \\[0.4cm]}
\vspace{3cm}

Description
\vspace{3cm}
\uppercase{My Name}
\vspace{3cm}
Professor Something

\vfill 
\HRule\\[0.1cm]
Santiago, Chile 2014




\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

https://www.writelatex.com/1862795gxzhvy#/4675483/

Comment: Please post a minimally working example, not just a fragment

Comment: Wrapfig does not behave well with `begin{center}`, I believe, I think you need a parbox for this

Comment: `wrapfig` is definitely the wrong tool for this

Comment: You should finish the groups with `\par`-> `{ \LARGE DEPARTAMENTO EDUCACIÓN \par}`

Comment: Also `wrapfig` has to be part of a paragraph. In this code it is on its own which makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wrapfig` is definitely the wrong tool for this.

Change the code into

```
\begin{center}

% You'll use the commented out line
\makebox[0pt][r]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{duck}}}
%\makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{uchile.png}}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
 \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
 \LARGE UNIVERSIDAD DE CHILE \\
 \LARGE FACSO \\
 \LARGE DEPARTAMENTO EDUCACIÓN
\end{tabular}}

\HRule

{\Huge TITLE \\[0.4cm]}

\vspace{3cm}
```

leaving the rest as is. Of course you'll remove the `duck` line and use the commented out one.

[image]

In order to vertically center the heading with respect to the picture, enclose the picture in a tabular and remove `[b]` from the second tabular:

```
\begin{center}

% You'll use the commented out lines
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{duck}}}%
\end{tabular}
%\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
%\makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{uchile.png}}
%\end{tabular}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
 \begin{tabular}{c}
 \LARGE UNIVERSIDAD DE CHILE \\
 \LARGE FACSO \\
 \LARGE DEPARTAMENTO EDUCACIÓN
\end{tabular}}

\HRule

{\Huge TITLE \\[0.4cm]}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your aswer. Is there a way to vertically center the text in relation to the image as in my example?

Comment: @Federico Added

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `wrapfig` and use a `tabular` environment to align the image an the University logo stuff.

The spacing can be adjusted later on.

I did not focus on the various `\vspace{}` commands...they are somehow weird, but that was not the question.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{wrapfig}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{./bild_erwin_schroedinger}
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}@{}}
 \LARGE UNIVERSIDAD DE CHILE \tabularnewline[0.1cm]
 \LARGE FACSO \tabularnewline[0.1cm]
 \LARGE DEPARTAMENTO EDUCACIÓN \tabularnewline[0.1cm]
\end{tabular} \tabularnewline
& \tabularnewline[\baselineskip]
\hline
& \tabularnewline[\baselineskip]
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ \Huge TITLE} \tabularnewline[0.4cm]
\end{tabular} 

\vspace{3cm}

Description
\vspace{3cm}
\uppercase{My Name}
\vspace{3cm}
Professor Something

\vfill 
%\HRule\\[0.1cm]
Santiago, Chile 2014




\end{titlepage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) but I prefer egreg's picture ;).

Comment: @cfr: Traitor :-P

Comment: There's a children's picture dictionary which has a duck (hwyaden) hidden somewhere on every page. I cannot see a duck image without being reminded of that... [There is an English version, too, but I did not know about that one until a few years ago. Don't know if there is a German version.]

Comment: @cfr: It might exist -- what's the English name of the book?

Comment: [Welsh](http://www.cwtshgloyn.co.uk/product/y-geiriadur-lliwgar/). [This](http://www.amazon.com/First-Thousand-German-Picture-English/dp/0746023073/ref=tmm_hrd_title_0?_encoding=UTF8&sr=1-9&qid=1417281051) is similar. (The Welsh is not 'First Thousand Words' but that's [what I find](http://www.amazon.com/First-Thousand-Words-Picture-Usborne/dp/0860202666/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1417281252&sr=1-3&keywords=children%27s+picture+dictionary+amery) for the English version as well. The Welsh is 'Children's Picture Dictionary'.) This is very off-topic...

Comment: @cfr: Something similar exists in German: http://www.amazon.de/Meine-allerersten-1000-W%C3%B6rter-Bildw%C3%B6rterbuch/dp/3811218689/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1417282955&sr=8-1&keywords=1000+erste+Worte+deutsch... I can't remember to have used it as a child, however.

Comment: Does it have ducks? We use y Geiriadur Lliwgar Plant in school but I also had a copy at home. I never had the English version, though.

Comment: @cfr: I don't know, I never read it and have no printed copy in my book shelves... I will investigate ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't center the heading "Universidad de..." relative to the page as in my example. This centers the heading in relation to the cell created to the right of the image.

Comment: @Federico: Did you say anything about centering? ;-) And giving feedback more than two months later is ... fill in yourself ;-)

Comment: @;-) Ok, thanks for your time, anyway.